# Functorial isomorphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator\Sh{Sh}\DeclareMathOperator\PSh{PSh}$We know that a presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on category $ \mathcal{C} $  gives a colimit preasheaf $ \mathcal{F}^{+} $ defined by Čech cohomology, and then we have the following theorem:
$ \mathcal{F}^{\sharp} = (\mathcal{F}^{+})^{+} $ is a sheaf and the canonical map induces a functorial isomorphism $ \Hom_{\PSh(\mathcal{C})}(\mathcal{F} , \mathcal{G}) = \Hom_{\Sh(\mathcal{C})}(\mathcal{F}^{\sharp} , \mathcal{G}) $,
for all $ \mathcal{G} $ in $ \Sh(\mathcal{C}) $.

My question is, can we can find a functorial isomorphism between
$ \Hom_{\PSh(\mathcal{C})}(\mathcal{F}^{+} , \mathcal{G}) $ and  $ \Hom_{\Sh(\mathcal{C})}(\mathcal{F}^{\sharp} ,  \mathcal{G}) $?

And the analogous question for $ \Hom_{\PSh(\mathcal{C})}(\mathcal{F} , \mathcal{G}) $ and $ \Hom_{\Sh(\mathcal{C})}((\mathcal{F}^{\sharp})^{+} ,  \mathcal{G}) $.

Comment: What if you apply your first isomorphism to $\mathscr F^+$ instead of $\mathscr F$?

Answer (score 3):

Since Čech cohomology is mentioned, I presume that $C$ is the category of open subsets of a topological space.
More generally, we can assume $C$ to be an arbitrary site.

In this case, the answer to both questions is yes.
It follows from a more general result:

If $G$ is a sheaf and $f\colon P\to Q$ is a local isomorphism of presheaves
(i.e., a morphism that becomes an isomorphism after passing to associated sheaves; in the case of sites with enough points, such as topological spaces, it can be described as a morphism that induces an isomorphism on all stalks),
then the induced map
$$\def\Hom{\mathop{\rm Hom}} \Hom(Q,G)→\Hom(P,G)$$
is an isomorphism.

This abstract result applies to the two cases under consideration
because the maps $F^+→F^\sharp$ and $F\to (F^\sharp)^+=F^\sharp$
are local isomorphisms.

Indeed, even more generally, the natural map $F\to F^+$ is a local isomorphism for any presheaf $F$.
Indeed, the associated sheaf functor can be computed as $F↦F^{++}$,
so if we apply it to the morphism $F→F^+$, we get the identity map $F^{++}→F^{+++}=F^{++}$.

In the case of sites with enough points, this also follows immediately from the fact that the stalk functor is cocontinuous, in particular, it preserves the colimit used to define $F^+$.

Comment: I think this answer is a bit misleading as it may imply there is something special about sheaves on topological spaces.  In fact the answer is yes for sheaves on any site, for formal reasons that have nothing to do with stalks.

Comment: @MikeShulman: I did not mention sites initially since the OP mentioned Čech cohomology, and more people are familiar with stalks than with arbitrary sites.  But now I added the general case, just to remove the ambiguity.